# No handler found for uri [/news] and method [POST]

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-jdbc, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have just started with `elastic search 5.5.2`. I am using `logstash-jdbc-input` plugin to push data from `mysql` database to `elastic search`. Here is logstash configuration that I am using

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/news"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "sunilgarg"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "../jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from news"
    }
}
output {
    stdout {codec => json_lines}
    elasticsearch {
        "index" => "news"
        "document_type" => "news"
        "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
        "document_id" => "%{id}"
    }
}
```

Now I am able to search using http://localhost:9200/news/_search with following body

```
{
   "query":{
      "query_string":{
         "query":"the"
      }
   }
}
```

Now this is searching even stop words that I don't want, So I tried analyzer by using this POST request http://localhost:9200/news with request body

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_english_analyzer": {
          "type": "standard",
          "max_token_length": 5,
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but this is showing

```
No handler found for uri [/news] and method [POST]
```

Am I missing something? Or I am getting this in a wrong way?

Please ignore if it is too basic to ask.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to create an index with settings in which case you want to use

```
PUT indexname
{
  // settings, mappings...
}
```

Comment: Read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html if you want to update settings. You might have to close the index. Better to start from scratch IMO.

Comment: above problem is solved. but still i can search with stop words like "the" :(

Comment: Did you apply the analyzer to your field?

Comment: Can you update your answer how can i apply this in proper way?